# Bare repositories and cloning

Tags: git

In this [link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-init), I found the following remark which doesn't make much sense to me (emphasis is mine):

> Bare Repositories
>
> The --bare flag creates a repository that doesn’t have a working
>   directory, making it impossible to edit files and commit changes in
>   that repository. **Central repositories should always be created as
>   bare repositories because pushing branches to a non-bare repository
>   has the potential to overwrite changes**. Think of --bare as a way to
>   mark a repository as a storage facility, opposed to a development
>   environment. This means that for virtually all Git workflows, the
>   central repository is bare, and developers local repositories are
>   non-bare.

Following the **Bare Repositories** section there is an **Example**, for which I didn't understand the following statement:

[image]

What's the difference between this statement and the use of the **git clone** command explained right after the **Example** in the link?

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that if you are working in any sort of centralized way, first you make a central repository that everybody will `pull` from and `push` to. You make that with `git init --bare`.

Then everybody clones from the central repository using `git clone <url_to_newly_created_repository>`

Answer (score -1):

Bare repositories do not yet contain file structures. Therefore, they can not be changed. When you create a repository on Github without any files, Github prompts you to first push a commit to the repository in order to create it; that is because the fresh repository on Github is a **bare** repository.

Developers do not work inside of bare repositories, because when you are working in a repository, it's a latter copy of the bare repository that actually does contain a file structure (it's not a bare repository anymore).

If you were working in a bare repository, there would be no file information that git was tracking, which forms a contradiction. A valid git repository with at least one commit is not bare, and a git repository without any commits is bare.

Understand this when you are hosting your own git repositories; the explanation given to you is valid, because it's telling you how to setup your own version of a repository. When you have a repository with no commits yet, it is a bare repository.

**git clone** fetches a repository's commit history from the central repository to your own local machine; a cloned repository must have at least one commit, therefore it is not bare.